# Jenkins: plugin installation failed:No manifest at /plugins/<plugin-name>/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to install Jenkins v 2.22 on a server(A) that has no internet access. I copied the jenkins.war and plugins from another server(B) which has internet access running and also has been running Jenkins very well for a while now. But after copy from B to A, when I start Jenkins on server A, I get the following error in log

`"
jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed 
SEVERE: Failed inspecting plugin /plugins/<plugin-name>.jpi 
java.io.IOexception: plugin installation failed:No manifest at /plugins/<plugin-name>/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"`.

1)Any idea how to fix this?

2)In the Jenkins configuration page I do not see the radio button for LDAP authorization; Is this how it is for Jenkins which runs on a server with no internet?

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: For people who are struggling with the same issue... here is what I found. When copying the plugins from server B to A, it did not retain the case sensitivity of the folders. For e.g , META-INF folder was coped as meta-inf. Jenkins looks for upper case folder name. Hence it could not read the manifest file. Now after re-copying, am able to successfully start Jenkins on server A and view all the plugins including LDAP. I can also see the LDAP radio button on the configuration page.